# Text based Python game, how to build a loop around the choices?

Tags: python

I am trying to design a game where you wake up in a room and there are only 3 doors to get out. You start with 4 choices (1. left door, 1. Right door, 3. Middle door, 4. Stay where you are). This will then take you to either certain death or 3 more doors. This happens again till either you eventually find your way out after choosing correctly or death. I have designed the following code which runs it through the first 4 choices, however after this I run a blank. I was thinking do I need a while loop in there or am I going about it wrong from the start.

```py
choice1 =   """
1: door on the left,
2: door on the right,
3: door in the middle,
4: Stay where you are and hope to be rescued"""

choice2 =   """
1: door on the left,
2: door on the right,
3: door in the middle,"""

door_left = """You have chosen the door on the left
are you sure? Y/N"""

door_right = """You have chosen the door on the right
are you sure? Y/N"""

door_middle = """You have chosen the door in the middle
are you sure? Y/N"""

axe = "A knight wielding a giant axe awaits you and chops off your head"

hole = """The room is pitch black and as you walk through you fall in to
a bottomless pit and spend the rest of your days falling in to darkness"""

crush = """The room in front of you is light and you believe
you have made the right choice, until you hear a noise and 
when you look up you can see the ceiling in becoming lower.
This continues until it crushes you in to the floor"""

good_choice = f"""Well done you have chosen well, however you 
are confronted by another 3 doors. Which door will you choose?
{choice2}"""

try_again = f"Ok choose another door {choice2}"

play = (input(f"""You have awoken in an empty low lit room with 
no windows and only three doors. You have no
idea how you got here but you know you have to 
choose one of the following
{choice1}\n"""))


    if play == "1":
        user_input = input(f"{door_left}")
    if user_input.lower() == "y":
        print({axe})
        
    elif play == "2":
        user_input = input(f"{door_middle}")
    if user_input.lower() == "y":
        print({hole})
        
    elif play == "3":
        user_input = input(f"{door_right}")
    if user_input.lower() == "y":
        user_input = print({good_choice})   
    
    elif play == "4":
        print("""You wait it out hoping to be saved
              1, 2, 3 days go by with none arriving
              eventually after many days of no food
              or water you become so dehydrated you
              fall over into a deep sleep never to
              awaken again.""")
    else:
        print("""You have failed too choose a correct 
              number, you hear all the doors lock and 
              a gas starts to appear from the walls. You 
              run over to the doors but they are all 
              locked, eventually the gas gets the better
              of you and you drift off into a forever
              slumber.""")
```

Comment: Putting some of the text in variables is weird; you are just making the code less cohesive. The initiative is not a bad one as such, but you probably need to start simple, and only go to a model where the program logic and the game map are completely separated from each other once you understand how.

Answer (score 0):

As @hannabanana123 pointed out, you have to adjust the indentation properly. You also have to add the loop with a termination condition. I have assumed that, once you die the game ends. Finally, if you want to change the question asked at each iteration once you get past the first door, you have to create a variable for it.

All in all, I have put together a first approximation to your code as follows:

```
choice1 = """
1: door on the left,
2: door in the middle,
3: door on the right,
4: Stay where you are and hope to be rescued"""

choice2 = """
1: door on the left,
2: door on the middle,
3: door in the right,"""

door_left = """You have chosen the door on the left
are you sure? Y/N"""

door_right = """You have chosen the door on the right
are you sure? Y/N"""

door_middle = """You have chosen the door in the middle
are you sure? Y/N"""

axe = "A knight wielding a giant axe awaits you and chops off your head"

hole = """The room is pitch black and as you walk through you fall in to
a bottomless pit and spend the rest of your days falling in to darkness"""

crush = """The room in front of you is light and you believe
you have made the right choice, until you hear a noise and 
when you look up you can see the ceiling in becoming lower.
This continues until it crushes you in to the floor"""

good_choice = f"""Well done you have chosen well, however you 
are confronted by another 3 doors. Which door will you choose?
{choice2}"""

try_again = f"Ok choose another door {choice2}"

done = False

question = f"""You have awoken in an empty low lit room with 
    no windows and only three doors. You have no
    idea how you got here but you know you have to 
    choose one of the following
    {choice1}\n"""

while not done:
    play = (input(f'{question}'))

    if play == "1":
        user_input = input(f"{door_left}")
        if user_input.lower() == "y":
            print(f'{axe}')
            done = True

    elif play == "2":
        user_input = input(f"{door_middle}")
        if user_input.lower() == "y":
            print(f'{hole}')
            done = True

    elif play == "3":
        user_input = input(f"{door_right}")
        if user_input.lower() == "y":
            question = f'{good_choice}'

    elif play == "4":
        print("""You wait it out hoping to be saved
                  1, 2, 3 days go by with none arriving
                  eventually after many days of no food
                  or water you become so dehydrated you
                  fall over into a deep sleep never to
                  awaken again.""")
        done = True
    else:
        print("""You have failed too choose a correct 
                  number, you hear all the doors lock and 
                  a gas starts to appear from the walls. You 
                  run over to the doors but they are all 
                  locked, eventually the gas gets the better
                  of you and you drift off into a forever
                  slumber.""")
        done = True
```

However, you can see that you have a lot of repetition in your code, so you could introduce a function for the "deaths"

```
def play_bad_choice(input_text, death_text):
    user_input = input(f"{input_text}")
    if user_input.lower() == "y":
        print(f'{death_text}')
        return True
    return False
```

This would cover options 1 and 2, where you ask for a confirmation and you die if you say "yes" or survive otherwise. You can also extend the function to cover the non-confirmed option 4 as follows:

```
def play_bad_choice(input_text, death_text):
    if input_text is not None:
        confirm_bad_choice = input(f"{input_text}")
    if input_text is None or confirm_bad_choice.lower() == "y":
        print(f'{death_text}')
        return True
    return False
```

Putting everything together it would look something like:

```
choice1 = """
1: door on the left,
2: door in the middle,
3: door on the right,
4: Stay where you are and hope to be rescued"""

choice2 = """
1: door on the left,
2: door on the middle,
3: door in the right,"""

door_left = """You have chosen the door on the left
are you sure? Y/N"""

door_right = """You have chosen the door on the right
are you sure? Y/N"""

door_middle = """You have chosen the door in the middle
are you sure? Y/N"""

axe = "A knight wielding a giant axe awaits you and chops off your head"

hole = """The room is pitch black and as you walk through you fall in to
a bottomless pit and spend the rest of your days falling in to darkness"""

crush = """The room in front of you is light and you believe
you have made the right choice, until you hear a noise and 
when you look up you can see the ceiling in becoming lower.
This continues until it crushes you in to the floor"""

good_choice = f"""Well done you have chosen well, however you 
are confronted by another 3 doors. Which door will you choose?
{choice2}"""

try_again = f"Ok choose another door {choice2}"

done = False

question = f"""You have awoken in an empty low lit room with 
    no windows and only three doors. You have no
    idea how you got here but you know you have to 
    choose one of the following
    {choice1}\n"""


def play_bad_choice(input_text, death_text):
    if input_text is not None:
        confirm_bad_choice = input(f"{input_text}")
    if input_text is None or confirm_bad_choice.lower() == "y":
        print(f'{death_text}')
        return True
    return False


while not done:
    play = (input(f'{question}'))

    if play == "1":
        done = play_bad_choice(door_left, axe)

    elif play == "2":
        done = play_bad_choice(door_middle, hole)

    elif play == "3":
        user_input = input(f"{door_right}")
        if user_input.lower() == "y":
            question = f'{good_choice}'

    elif play == "4":
        done = play_bad_choice(None, """You wait it out hoping to be saved
1, 2, 3 days go by with none arriving
eventually after many days of no food
or water you become so dehydrated you
fall over into a deep sleep never to
awaken again.""")
    else:
        done = play_bad_choice(None, """You have failed too choose a correct 
number, you hear all the doors lock and 
a gas starts to appear from the walls. You 
run over to the doors but they are all 
locked, eventually the gas gets the better
of you and you drift off into a forever
slumber.""")
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you Pablo that is an amazing answer. Going forward if I wanted to change the out come of the door that is chosen so it isn't always the same and even the other option written is this possible?

Comment: You could pass a dictionary of `{option: (text, death)}` at each stage, and even create the dictionary randomly